# Running/Loading OBJ files in Java

Tags: java

I'd like to run a Maya OBJ file (i don't think it matters if it's from maya or not) inside java. 
I already built a 3D-model inside Maya and i exported it as an OBJ file (.obj). 
i'm interested in building applications for Andriod and i'm working with eclipse, i'm really new at these things but i would very much appreciated it if you know any tutorials/sites that would help me learn more about such issues like loading an OBJ file into java and running it inside an application.

it would be also amazing if anyone could provide me with a code on how i can load and run such a thing in Java.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233987/java-loading-obj-files

Comment: @om-nom-nom I disagree - the first question you referenced is specifically targeted towards JOGL, the second is only interested in textual data from the file.

Comment: @berry120 well, I've missed that op wants to work with android. Anyways, there is already an question for it too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162667/android-opengl-obj-file-loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe JMonkey [can load this format](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3abeginner%3ahello_asset#model_file_formats), has good scenegraph support, and has relatively new (but developing) [Android integration](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3aandroid).

Answer (score 1):

When you want to parse a file format, like OBJ, all you need to do is read the spec and write a function that parses it. This is much simpler for text based formats like .OBJ.

You can read the .OBJ spec [here](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec).

An implementation of an .OBJ loader in Java can be found [here](http://fabiensanglard.net/Mykaruga/index.php).